# What's the proper way to comment a constructor in a generic class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stylecop, xml-documentation

What's the proper way to comment this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Repository"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="unitOfWork">The unit of work.</param>
public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

VS complains about it:

> Warning   11  XML comment on
> 'Data.Repository.Repository(Data.IUnitOfWork)' has cref attribute
> 'Repository' that could not be
> resolved  C:\Projects\xx\yy\DataAccess\Repository.cs  35  58  Data

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to use curly braces:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Repository{T}"/> class.
/// </summary>
```

For each `typeparam`, just add an additional value in the braces, delimited with a comma.

Comment: You can also use angled brackets as XML entities `&lt;T&gt;`. Of course, curly braces are much more convenient :)

Comment: BTW, "Initializes a new instance of the Repository class." (without <see> tag) will be also OK for StyleCop.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple generic types, you can do something like this: `<see cref="KeyedCollection{TKey,TItem}"/>`

Answer (score 5):

StyleCop has defined how it should [look like](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1642.html).

> If the class contains generic parameters, these can be annotated within the cref link using either of the following two formats:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Customer`1"/> class.
/// </summary>
public Customer()
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Customer{T}"/> class.
/// </summary>
public Customer()
{
}
```